# BAZEL remote-cache, multi servers

Tags: bazel

We have two caching servers for BAZEL build. Both servers may not be synchronized. Is that possible to use one of them to fetch and if failed, then use the other one? Later on, build local if this is a new build.
It could be something like
`--remote_cache=http://server1;=http://server2`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for seems HA capablity. What I suggest is that you can set up a HA front end in front of remote cache service.